# What do the x axis really represent in this fourier transform and how to convert it?

Tags: matlab

This is a question for a hand in in one of my courses, just want to state that.

What I am trying to do is sampling a square wave, take the fourier transform (fft) and plot the answer to graph. This is how I have achieved this:

```
Fs = 100;
Ts = 1/Fs;
N = 8192;

Tmax = (N - 1)*Ts;
t = 0:Ts:Tmax;

x = square(t);
X = fft(x,N);

plot(t, abs(X))
```

What it return is a graph that looks like this

[image: The graph]

This looks almost as inspected, but since I do not know what to expect with the square wave I also try to do it with a $\sin(2*t)$ wave. If I take the fourier transform on this, I should get 2 spiks, each at 2 and -2 (right side). But what I get is something like this

[image: Zoomed in on the interesting part]

(Note! I have zoomed in on the left hand side of the graph to show that the spike is not at 2) As you can see the spike is not where it is supposed to be. I can than conclude that probably the 1 graph is not eater how it should be.

Is it something wrong with my x axis representation? And if so, how do I convert the x axis into the frequency plane?

Comment: I just replaced x = square(t) with x = sin(2*t) in the code above. Thank you, will try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frequencies resulting from the FFT range from 0 to the sampling frequency. Specifically, the horizontal axis of the FFT corresponds to frequencies `0`, `fs/N`, `2*fs/N`, ... ,`(N-1)*fs/N`, where `fs` is the sample frequency and `N` is the FFT size.

So, you should modify the horizontal axis in the plot to the following, where `N` is `numel(t)` and `fs` is computed as `1/(t(2)-t(1))`:

```
freq_axis = (0:numel(t)-1)/numel(t)/(t(2)-t(1));
plot(freq_axis, abs(X))
```

You may also want to apply [`fftshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) to observe frequencies from `-fs/2` to `fs/2`, instead of from `0` to `fs`. In that case:

```
freq_axis = (-numel(t)/2:numel(t)/2-1)/numel(t)/(t(2)-t(1));
plot(freq_axis, fftshift(abs(X)))
```

As a check, with your example `x = sin(2*t)` the second plot gives:

[image]

Comparing your `sin(2*t)` with the generic expression `sin(2*pi*f*t)`, the frequency `f` of that sinusoid is seen to be `1/pi = 0.3183`,  in agreement with the figure.

Comment: Now I can see that it actually goes to Fs, so this looks correct! Ty! But something still bugging me is that if I do the exact same thing, but with sin(2t) instead of square(t), should I not get a spike at 2 in the x axis? If not I feel I really have to go back and start over with what a fourier series is and how it is used

Comment: This makes so much sense! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Salviati Glad I could help!